# HTML, R markdown table is too wide

Tags: html, html-table, r-markdown

I'm trying to add this R markdown that I have to my HTML page, but this one table is too wide I tried using `<div class="scrollit">` with it but it won't work and I have no idea how to fix it.

I've been searching and trying with no luck, this is my first time creating an R markdown, so I would appreciate any help.

This is a [Picture of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cN8uH.png) of how the table looks in the browser

This is the table code in HTML:

```
<div class="knitsql-table">
<table>
<caption>Displaying records 1 - 10</caption>
<colgroup>
<col width="7%" />
<col width="5%" />
<col width="8%" />
<col width="8%" />
<col width="5%" />
<col width="5%" />
<col width="11%" />
<col width="7%" />
<col width="12%" />
<col width="6%" />
<col width="4%" />
<col width="4%" />
<col width="3%" />
<col width="4%" />
<col width="5%" />
</colgroup>
<thead>
<tr class="header">
<th align="left">ride_id</th>
<th align="left">rideable_type</th>
<th align="left">started_at</th>
<th align="left">ended_at</th>
<th align="left">ride_length</th>
<th align="right">day_of_week</th>
<th align="left">start_station_name</th>
<th align="left">start_station_id</th>
<th align="left">end_station_name</th>
<th align="left">end_station_id</th>
<th align="right">start_lat</th>
<th align="right">start_lng</th>
<th align="right">end_lat</th>
<th align="right">end_lng</th>
<th align="left">member_casual</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="odd">
<td align="left">00000065B3150FF2</td>
<td align="left">electric_bike</td>
<td align="left">2023-09-24 12:56:50</td>
<td align="left">2023-09-24 13:00:43</td>
<td align="left">00:03:53</td>
<td align="right">1</td>
<td align="left">Sheridan Rd &amp; Noyes St (NU)</td>
<td align="left">604</td>
<td align="left">University Library (NU)</td>
<td align="left">605</td>
<td align="right">42.05820</td>
<td align="right">-87.67743</td>
<td align="right">42.05294</td>
<td align="right">-87.67345</td>
<td align="left">casual</td>
</tr>
<tr class="even">
<td align="left">0000085FE82E5429</td>
<td align="left">electric_bike</td>
<td align="left">2023-04-13 17:52:05</td>
<td align="left">2023-04-13 18:10:33</td>
<td align="left">00:18:28</td>
<td align="right">5</td>
<td align="left">NA</td>
<td align="left">NA</td>
<td align="left">Halsted St &amp; 18th St</td>
<td align="left">13099</td>
<td align="right">41.88000</td>
<td align="right">-87.63000</td>
<td align="right">41.85751</td>
<td align="right">-87.64599</td>
<td align="left">member</td>
</tr>
<tr class="odd">
<td align="left">0000089D36728778</td>
<td align="left">docked_bike</td>
<td align="left">2023-05-08 13:22:50</td>
<td align="left">2023-05-08 13:28:53</td>
<td align="left">00:06:03</td>
<td align="right">2</td>
<td align="left">Clark St &amp; Lake St</td>
<td align="left">KA1503000012</td>
<td align="left">Sedgwick St &amp; Huron St</td>
<td align="left">TA1307000062</td>
<td align="right">41.88602</td>
<td align="right">-87.63088</td>
<td align="right">41.89467</td>
<td align="right">-87.63844</td>
<td align="left">casual</td>
</tr>
<tr class="even">
<td align="left">00000B15294F9057</td>
<td align="left">electric_bike</td>
<td align="left">2023-12-08 17:52:37</td>
<td align="left">2023-12-08 18:00:54</td>
<td align="left">00:08:17</td>
<td align="right">6</td>
<td align="left">NA</td>
<td align="left">NA</td>
<td align="left">NA</td>
<td align="left">NA</td>
<td align="right">41.90000</td>
<td align="right">-87.75000</td>
<td align="right">41.90000</td>
<td align="right">-87.76000</td>
<td align="left">casual</td>
</tr>
<tr class="odd">
<td align="left">000010D58FFC4A2B</td>
<td align="left">electric_bike</td>
<td align="left">2023-11-10 17:46:50</td>
<td align="left">2023-11-10 17:59:41</td>
<td align="left">00:12:51</td>
<td align="right">6</td>
<td align="left">NA</td>
<td align="left">NA</td>
<td align="left">Ashland Ave &amp; Division St</td>
<td align="left">13061</td>
<td align="right">41.88000</td>
<td align="right">-87.65000</td>
<td align="right">41.90345</td>
<td align="right">-87.66775</td>
<td align="left">member</td>
</tr>
<tr class="even">
<td align="left">0000140539E54BF2</td>
<td align="left">classic_bike</td>
<td align="left">2023-06-21 20:19:43</td>
<td align="left">2023-06-21 20:32:04</td>
<td align="left">00:12:21</td>
<td align="right">4</td>
<td align="left">Sheffield Ave &amp; Webster Ave</td>
<td align="left">TA1309000033</td>
<td align="left">Milwaukee Ave &amp; Wabansia Ave</td>
<td align="left">13243</td>
<td align="right">41.92154</td>
<td align="right">-87.65382</td>
<td align="right">41.91262</td>
<td align="right">-87.68139</td>
<td align="left">member</td>
</tr>
<tr class="odd">
<td align="left">000019B6351D28DF</td>
<td align="left">electric_bike</td>
<td align="left">2024-01-12 01:14:51</td>
<td align="left">2024-01-12 01:19:56</td>
<td align="left">00:05:05</td>
<td align="right">6</td>
<td align="left">May St &amp; Taylor St</td>
<td align="left">13160</td>
<td align="left">Racine Ave &amp; 15th St</td>
<td align="left">13304</td>
<td align="right">41.86942</td>
<td align="right">-87.65542</td>
<td align="right">41.86127</td>
<td align="right">-87.65663</td>
<td align="left">member</td>
</tr>
<tr class="even">
<td align="left">00001F1414872B6A</td>
<td align="left">electric_bike</td>
<td align="left">2023-10-21 17:49:34</td>
<td align="left">2023-10-21 18:08:26</td>
<td align="left">00:18:52</td>
<td align="right">7</td>
<td align="left">N Green St &amp; W Lake St</td>
<td align="left">20246</td>
<td align="left">Larrabee St &amp; Webster Ave</td>
<td align="left">13193</td>
<td align="right">41.88558</td>
<td align="right">-87.64843</td>
<td align="right">41.92182</td>
<td align="right">-87.64414</td>
<td align="left">casual</td>
</tr>
<tr class="odd">
<td align="left">000023AB39488896</td>
<td align="left">electric_bike</td>
<td align="left">2023-09-19 16:50:40</td>
<td align="left">2023-09-19 17:06:13</td>
<td align="left">00:15:33</td>
<td align="right">3</td>
<td align="left">California Ave &amp; Winona St</td>
<td align="left">443</td>
<td align="left">Leavitt St &amp; Belmont Ave</td>
<td align="left">KA17018068</td>
<td align="right">41.97478</td>
<td align="right">-87.69781</td>
<td align="right">41.93935</td>
<td align="right">-87.68328</td>
<td align="left">member</td>
</tr>
<tr class="even">
<td align="left">000028BC6D9349BE</td>
<td align="left">electric_bike</td>
<td align="left">2023-12-15 13:42:48</td>
<td align="left">2023-12-15 13:45:41</td>
<td align="left">00:02:53</td>
<td align="right">6</td>
<td align="left">Kingsbury St &amp; Kinzie St</td>
<td align="left">KA1503000043</td>
<td align="left">Clinton St &amp; Washington Blvd</td>
<td align="left">WL-012</td>
<td align="right">41.88925</td>
<td align="right">-87.63855</td>
<td align="right">41.88338</td>
<td align="right">-87.64117</td>
<td align="left">member</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```